# How to delete a particular textbox when particular button is clicked?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#minus" + data1[i].PhoneNo[j] + "").on("click", function () {
    $("#textbox" + data1[i].PhoneNo[j] + "").find("input").remove();
});
```

When I am trying to click the button which is aside the text box,I could not able to delete that particular text box.Can anyone help me out to solve the problem.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: can you paste html code also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: No need to create click handler for each button, you can fallow some common way to register the click handler and delete textbox. Please share your html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better if you can share your HTML code snippet, then it is easier to construct js code, anyway here is the illustration made for you :

**Html**(let say all of these created by loop process)

```
// put class name on button for references
// 1st group
<input type="text" class="a" value="a"><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button>
<input type="text" class="a" value="b"><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button>
<input type="text" class="a" value="b"><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button>

// 2nd group
// this code wrapped inside parent container
<hr/>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="a" value="a" />
  <button class="removeBtn2">Remove</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="a" value="b" />
  <button class="removeBtn2">Remove</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="a" value="c" />
  <button class="removeBtn2">Remove</button>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// for first group of textbox
$(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function() {   
   // Must be noted that, textbox must be aside with button
   // that why we asked for HTML snippet 
   $(this).prev().remove().end().remove();
   // or $(this).prev('.a').remove().end().remove();     
});

// for second group of textbox
$(document).on('click', '.removeBtn2', function () {
  // just remove it parents
  $(this).closest('.container').remove(); 
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/azt65jfc/3/)**

Comment: Yes .What you have sent now is exactly right.It worked.Thank You

Comment: @NagaBhavani make sure about this "It's better if you can share your HTML code snippet,"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9gccfw73/

In the above fiddle,as iam getting the output,but at text boxes when iam appeding a button and  click on the button aside the text box that particular text box must be deleted.

Comment: @NagaBhavani : do you mean when close button was clicked, then all the textbox appeared should be disappeared right? if so, then try this https://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/9gccfw73/7/

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali: I mean that as we are viewing all the details as an output.If we want to edit that particular details ,for example,if i want to delete One number from PhoneNo i should have a button beside each textbox.When i click that particular button that number in the text box and textbox must be deleted.

Comment: Acctually i do't get it about `,if i want to delete One number from PhoneNo i should have a button beside each textbox`, then why not create that button.